# Upload CSV file into MySql

Tags: php, mysql, csv, mysqli

I'm trying to create a simple form to upload CSV files into MySql using MySQLi Object-oriented. The connection to the DB works fine but for some reason that I haven't figured out yet it doesn't insert the data from the CSV file into the DB.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "user_name";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db_name";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if($_FILES['file']['name']) {
        $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
        if ($filename[1] == 'csv') {

            $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
            while($data = fgetcsv($handle)) {
                $user_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[1]);
                $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[2]);
                $last_mod = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[3]);

                $sql="INSERT into user (user_id, name, last_mod) VALUES ('$user_id', '$name', '$last_mod')";
                if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
                die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
                }
                echo "1 record added";
            }

            $conn->close();
        }
    }

}

<form action="index.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="beer">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="file">Select your file:</label>
<input name="file" type="file">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox">I agree!</label>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but where are you setting `$row`?

Comment: @andrewsi ...sorry that was the old version, I have changed it to "data"

Comment: what's wrong with `LOAD DATA INFILE`?

Comment: @e4c5...never used before...Do I have to replace the INSERT with LOAD DATA INFILE?

Comment: You need to do some debugging, and figure out where it's not working. You've got nested if statements - are they all evaluating true? (You're exploding the filename on `,`, rather than `.`, so are you certain that the file ends in `,csv`, for example?

Comment: @andrewsi...I have changed that one...still not working

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: May I know why the -1 vote ?

Comment: **You need to do some debugging, and figure out where it's not working. You've got nested if statements - are they all evaluating true?** the comment above is not about exploding the filename on ",". It's about verification of every friggin' step. Which nobody can do but your self.

Answer (score -1):

1. please check file type. It must be .csv.
2. Please check your csv file and remove the row where you wrote column name.